# echo php in an inline css background-image deletes '/' in url

Tags: php, html, css, echo, inline

Ive read through some of the other topics but i couldnt find a solution that worked. But someway the the url shows up as  `http:="" mysite.com="" wp-content="" uploads="" 2015="" 08="" matchups-1.png"`)

This is the code I'm using. How do I prevent it from adding the extra `""` and spaces?

```
<div style="background-image: url("<?php echo $bgimage; ?>"); background-position:cover;"></div>
```

I've tried to code like this, but this didnt work:

```
<div style="background-image: url(\'<?php echo $bgimage; ?>\'); background-position:cover;"></div>
```

as some answers suggested but still I'm either doing something wrong or it doesn't work. Can anyone tell me a solution? thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply use

```
<div style="background-image: url('<?php echo $bgimage; ?>'); background-position:cover;"></div>
```

or

```
<div style="background-image: url(<?php echo $bgimage; ?>); background-position:cover;"></div>
```

quotes are not necessary in an url

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the double quote `"` character you use for `url()`. Just try without or with a single quote instead.

```
<div style="background-image: url(<?php echo $bgimage; ?>); background-position:cover;"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

you should solve it with 3 ways..

1. put this in the

```css
<style type="text/css">
    .logo {
    background: url(<?php echo $img_url; ?>);
    }
    </style>
```

2. Or you can simply use the inline style attribute and define the background-image.

   ```
   <div style="background-image: url(<?php echo $img_url; ?>);">
   ```
3. or With the use of JQuery

```html
<input type="text" class="imgcntnt" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var input_image = $('input.imgcntnt').val();
        $('body').css('background', 'url(' + input_image + ')');
  </script>
```